# Access element attributes in XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I am using Perl to parse an XML file.

[This tutorial](http://interoperating.info/courses/perl4data/node/26) tells me how to access elements in the XML file, which I can do fine, but how would I access the author *id number* from the following?

```
<booklist>
   <book>
      <authors>
          <author id="54"/>
          <author id="76"/>
      </authors>
      <title>Book 1 title</title>
      <isbn>Book1ISBN</isbn>
   </book>
</booklist>
```

Comment: The best advice you will receive is ***don't use `XML::Simple`***. It's own documentation says, *"The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces."*

Comment: I'm not a perl person, so I'm not sure if this helps - are you able to adapt an XPath query to get a list of the author ID values? If so, here's an XPath expression you could use:

//author/@id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read in many posts that `XML::Simple` is not suitable for medium or complex parsing tasks (this is not one of them). I like `XML::Twig`, so I recommend it, and will write an example that gets the job done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '/booklist/book/authors/author' => sub {
            printf qq|%s\n|, $_->att('id');           
        },  
    },  
)->parsefile(shift);
```

In `twig_handlers` you put a `xpath` expression and an anonymous function with the element as the special variable `$_`, so you only need to access its attribute with the `att()` function.

Run it with an argument, like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
54
76
```

Comment: The OP's question links to a page that uses nothing but `XML::Simple`. I don't think you're helping by saying that it's fine to use that module here, and then go on to give an example using `XML::Twig`. The question is *"how would I access the author id number"* (implicitly *using `XML::Simple`)) and the answer isn't a script that uses `XML::Twig` to list the `id` attributes of all `author` elements.

Comment: I do not have to use xml simple. It was the first thing I found.